# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0. Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, sdk

I am running my project using vscode and I always push my code to GitHub with no issues from the azure extension in vscode. The I see this issue when I open GitHub and see this error message there. here is the complete error:

> Error: /home/runner/.dotnet/sdk/6.0.418/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(144,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 6.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. [/home/runner/work/HSPA-NEW/HSPA-NEW/API/API.csproj]
> 0 Warning(s)
> 1 Error(s)
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.51
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Why I am getting this error and how to fix that?